# Unity C# script dictionary initializer not part of C# 4.0 language specification

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, initializer

I am stuck with the following error being repeated in my code in my Unity project

Assets/App/Models/AnnotationModel.cs(39,17): error CS1644: Feature `dictionary initializer' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

The code that is triggering a block of these errors is the following

```
["CameraPose"] = ConvertToken(CameraPose),
["Aspect"] = Aspect,
["Image"] = Image.Id,
["Fov"] = Fov,
["IsAnchored"] = IsAnchored,
["AnchorPosition"] = ConvertToken(AnchorPosition),
["DrawLines"] = ConvertToken(DrawLines),
["SurfaceDrawLines"] = ConvertToken(SurfaceDrawLines)
```

What is the new way to initialize a C# dictionary? I have tried (unsuccessfully) to find the updated version of the initialization in the C# 4.0 language specification.
If it helps, the following code shows what these objects are

```
public Pose CameraPose;
public float Aspect;
public ImageModel Image;
[Range(0, 120)] public float Fov = 60;
public bool IsAnchored;
public Vector3 AnchorPosition;
public List<List<Vector2>> DrawLines;
public List<List<Vector3>> SurfaceDrawLines;
```

Any help at all would be appreciated! I am completely new to Unity and C#.

Comment: [Index Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#index-initializers) are a feature of C# 6. Since you are using an older version you can't use it and need to assign elements "by hand". (Although newer versions of Unity3D allow you to use C# 6 as well)

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You ask what the *new* way is to initialize a dictionary, but you already know what it is; you're trying to use it.  It doesn't work because, as UnholySheep notes, the feature was added to C# 6 and you're using C# 4, which shipped *eight years ago*. I am also confused as to why you are looking for C# 6 features to be mentioned in the C# 4 specification. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 6):

> What is the new way to initialize a C# dictionary? I have tried
>   (unsuccessfully) to find the updated version of the initialization in
>   the C# 4.0 language specification.

It seems like you think the way you are initializing the dictionary became obsolete and you need to find the new way of doing it. It just the **reverse**! The way you are initializing a dictionary is a [new feature](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2015/04/C-Sharp-Dictionary-Initializers.aspx), added to the language in the version c#6.0. But Unity3d uses, by default c#4.0, an older version of the language.

You have 2 options here:

1. Adjust your code to use the [syntax avaliable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer) until c#4.0.

Probably something like:

```
{"CameraPose", ConvertToken(CameraPose)},
{"Aspect", Aspect},
{"Image", Image.Id},
{"Fov", Fov},
{"IsAnchored", IsAnchored},
{"AnchorPosition", ConvertToken(AnchorPosition)},
{"DrawLines", ConvertToken(DrawLines)},
{"SurfaceDrawLines", ConvertToken(SurfaceDrawLines)}
```

2. Configure your project in Unity to use a more recent version of the language.

Follow [these instructions](https://trymnilsen.com/articles/2017-07/using-csharp6-dotnet45-in-unity3d):

```
Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings->Configuration->Scripting Runtime Version
```